# Expected comma error in macro function

Tags: macros, masm, x86-16

My Masm 8086 is showing an error "expected:comma" when I used this macro..

```
Pack macro p1,p2
Move al,p1
Mov q,0ah
Mul q
Add p2
Endm
```

Then I called it in code segment by:

```
Pack ch,cl
```

It's showing an error of expected comma in the macro call line.

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least a couple of syntactic errors in your code:

`Move` should probably be `mov`:

```
Move al,p1
```

---

`Add` needs two operands:

```
Add p2
```